# Kotlin how to launch an async processing from android.app.Application

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions, android-ktx

I am new to Kotlin and trying to start an async backend call inside **android.app.Application**

```
import android.app.Application;

class App: Application {

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    fetchDataFromBackend()
  }

  fun fetchDataFromBackend() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
      // Fetches data from backed.
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that **lifecycleScope.launch** cannot be used from an Application, I have done the same from Activity/Fragments and viewModelScope for my viewModel.

I wish to do the same inside the Application, does anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: For better understanding, may I ask what your scenario is, getting data from your backend within the `App` class? Why is the Activity or Fragment not an option for you?

Comment: Its for fetching user preferences that is required for the entire app life-cycle not restricted to any activity.

Comment: I see, thanks. The issue with the `App` class is that it does not have a proper lifecycle like Activity. So you could not cancel your request properly if you need to, like you could do within Activity. Have you considered a Single Activity approach, from were you could do this? I honestly do not know what is best practice for your scenario. I usually avoid doing any complex logic within `App` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`ProcessLifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner), which has the same lifecycle as the `Application` object.

```
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycleScope.launch {
  // Fetches data from backend
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this is not guaranteed to be called soon after your app is send to background. So it's not ideal for cleaning up tasks and memory that are no longer required.

Comment: You are correct. Running in this scope is like running in a Thread or AsyncTask – it doesn't keep your process alive, so if there are no other services or activities that are running, the OS may kill your app process.

The OP mentioned it is for fetching user preferences, so I assumed that if there are no other components running, the fetch action is not meaningful, and so it's OK for the app to be killed in the middle of this coroutine.